# 500 Internal Server Error after moving index.php

Tags: craft3

Installed using composer. No issues. Installed in /craft directory. Used the command line setup with what seemed like no issues. Moved my files from /craft/web to /public_html. When I try to get the site I get a 500 error. I CAN get http://domain.com/phpinfo.php. What could be the issue?

*Edit*
I changed file permission of index.php to 644 and now get a different page with the same error. The first page is the standard cpanel 500 error with formatting. The second error page is a less formatted 500 page:

> This page isn’t working
>   67.227.155.172 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your Craft path accordingly. When you move your `web` folder, you have to edit your index.php obviously.

Your php file does not magically know where your vendor folder is

Comment: Yeah...I tried that.
I tried every path I could think of. Nothing worked. The only path I got a different result from is //craft. With that path I got this error HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException

Comment: I do now have a error_log showing up in my public_html. The last line is [10-Mar-2018 23:44:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/craft/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/recoveryfinder/public_html/index.php on line 12

Comment: When you receive the `NotFoundHttpException` everything is fine. Since you probably don't have any templates it's normal to receive this

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. For those who come here for this issue if you move your web folder or the files in the web forler you have to tell the index page where you installed craft. In my case it was the FULL path for that user: ex /home/user/craftinstallation

Comment: Would you mind marking the question as solved then?